# How did Richie Rich's family become the richest family in the world?

Tags: richie-rich, harvey-comics

*Richie Rich* has been a Harvey Comics book "Richest boy in the world" character for decades. And his family was rich, it seems, some generations prior to his birth. I could see them growing more wealthy with successive generations, but **how** did they get their *initial* wealth?

Comment: I've voted to leave this closed. I believe this fits into point 3 in this answer on meta: [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/344/68872). While the show has sci-fi and fantastical (SFF-nal) elements, it's not inherently SFF-nal. As such asking about such elements would be on-topic but a question about how they became rich or any other questions not about the SFF-nal elements would not be on-topic.

Comment: Unless there is any specific marketing to suggest it's SFF-nal, and the "central conceit" requires acceptance of SFF-nal concepts to believe the plot, it's not on topic. In this case I have no evidence to suggest such marketing exists (although my search was short), however some strips may require acceptance of some SFF-nal concepts, as such I believe asking about those would be on-topic but asking about other things would not be.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Richie Rich has been on topic for almost its entire run. Robots, ghosts, monsters, science gizmos and doodads abound, not to mention time travel; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/is-richie-rich-on-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Richie's ancestors, right back to prehistoric times, were blessed with a superpower that can best be described as *'extreme financial luck'*. Whenever an opportunity presents itself for the universe to give them piles of money, gems or valuable assets, it happens, pretty much irregardless of whether the person wants it or not.

His family came to America on the Mayflower. Almost immediately they were given land by the Snobsdale Indians.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Richie Rich #11](https://harveycomics.fandom.com/wiki/Richie_Rich_11)</sup></sub>

His pioneering ancestor bought a small parcel of land that turned out to contain a mountain made of gold and a river flowing with oil.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Richie Rich #46](https://harveycomics.fandom.com/wiki/Richie_Rich_46)</sup></sub>

Even back in stoneage time, Richie's credulous cave-dwelling ancestors were so rich that their wealth attracted the attention of thieves, but they still ended up on top.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Richie Rich #157](https://harveycomics.fandom.com/wiki/Richie_Rich_157)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well...that does explain a lot. And the fact that their wealth stemmed from such fantastical elements makes me feel validated about asking it here. Thanks, V.